# Magento says tax rules already exists while all rules are deleted

Tags: magento

I am setting up my magento tax rules and I get the following message:

> Rules () already exist for the specified Tax Rate, Customer Tax Class
> and Product Tax Class combinations

This while I only have two very simple rules setup that do not macht the combinations. Can it be possible that magento has the old rules saved somewhere?

Comment: Maybe this similar is  answered http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26117/canada-tax-rule-set-up-magento-ce-1-9-0-1

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion magento does not cascade some deletions correctly: in tax_calculation remain some orphan rows which should be deleted manually.

See https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/44504/3515 for details.